# Need to remove unwanted space element

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I want to remove the unwanted space element using XSL.

XML I'm testing:

```
<Body>
   <h1>abc</h1>
   <h1>efg</h1>
   <p>efgh</p>
   <h1> </h1>
</Body>
```

XSL I used:

```
<xsl:template match="Body">
   <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="boolean(self::h1)">
         <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
               <h1>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()/node()"/>
               </h1>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
               <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
         </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Output I get:

```
<Body>
   <h1>abcefg</h1>
   <p>efgh</p>
   <h1> </h1>
</Body>
```

Output I would like:

```
<Body>
   <h1>abcefg</h1>
   <p>efgh</p>
</Body>
```

I need to remove the element having the space value. Please advise. Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you need to explain in more detail how your input can look like and which result you want, what is supposed to happen if the last `h1` element is not empty or filled with white space only but contains some data? Do you want to a new group of `h1` elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming, by the way you've written your XSL document, that you only wish to merge the `h1` elements. I'm further assuming that you *only* wish to remove "blank" `h1` elements. (It's a very simple modification if any of these assumptions aren't true.)

With that in mind, here's one way of achieving the required output:

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="h1" />
<xsl:template match="Body">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="boolean(self::h1)">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
          <xsl:if test="string-length(current-group()) > 0">
            <xsl:copy>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
            <xsl:copy>
              <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:copy>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

With an expanded XML input to showcase my assumptions:

```
<Body>
  <h1>abc</h1>
  <h1>efg</h1>
  <p>efgh</p>
  <p>ijkl</p>
  <h2>mnop</h2>
  <h1> </h1>
  <p> </p>
</Body>
```

the output is:

```
<Body>
  <h1>abcefg</h1>
  <p>efgh</p>
  <p>ijkl</p>
  <h2>mnop</h2>
  <p> </p>
</Body>
```

The key to the solution is the `xsl:strip-space` element coupled with the `string-length()` function. This actually results in every `h1` element with *any* amount of, and only, white space being removed.

I also fixed a major bug at the second `xsl:apply-templates` element which would result in every consecutive, non `h1`  sequence of elements being merged together naked. (You need to loop through all the nodes in the `current-group()` node set to avoid this.)